# Revised simplex singular basis

Tags: simplex, operations-research

Am I right that the basis in the revised simplex should never be singular?

I programmed the algorithm by my own and after several hundreds of steps the basis becomes singular.

Does this might be occur due to a rounding error somewhere and is there any standard behavior how to get around this?

Normally a singular matrix means that the problem is infeasible, right?

In my problem I'm 100% sure that it is feasible.

So the main question is: Is it "normal" that a basis might be singular due to rounding errors? And also how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the basis matrix should never be singular.

Yes, rounding error could account for this.

There are three things that might help avoid it (two algorithmic, one related to the model being solved). First, never invert the basis matrix. It's both slow and (I think) more vulnerable than other methods to rounding problems. Use some kind of matrix factorization (LU, SVD, ...). I don't write solvers, so I can't recommend a specific one over the others.

Typically the factorization is updated incrementally with each pivot, rather than refactoring the basis matrix each time. So the second suggestion is to periodically refactor the basis matrix, to flush out accumulated rounding errors.

The third (model related) suggestion is to avoid having both very large magnitude and very small magnitude constraint coefficients. Once the ratio of the largest to the smallest (nonzero) coefficient gets up around 10^14 (give or take), you're begging for rounding problems.

Note: If you programmed it the way it's taught in introductory books (pivoting via Gaussian elimination), and you want to stick with that, then at least adopt a version of refactoring. Every so often, go back to the original tableau and pivot on the columns of the current basis matrix (ignoring the reduced costs), to get back to the current basis. That will shake out some decimal dust.

No, a singular basis matrix does not mean the problem is infeasible: it means you don't have a valid basis.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. The weird thing is that I refactor the basis matrix every step so I always work on the original tableau. I implemented the pivoting via Gaussian elimination version as well and that one works fine on this task but fails on others, therefore I wanted to use the revised method which should be more accurate and normally be faster.

Comment: If you coded the basis factoring from scratch, you might consider trying a (well-tested) library routine. Also, you could try running the problem that produces the singular basis matrix with some breakpoints or print statements to look for suspicious numerical operations (such as pivoting on an entry close enough to zero that it might be decimal dust).

Comment: I am using scipy lu_factor and lu_solve for it. Figured out that the leaving variable is the part which seems wrong in my example. The division of the right hand side by the d where BD=a and a is the entering column. The division gives me 4 similar values all around 0.121212121212 and different after a couple of decimal places. I then choose the minimum which in my case is the wrong one and then the next right hand side is negative which gives also gives me a singular matrix in the following step.

Comment: It's a bit of a kludge, but you can try truncating really small (magnitude) right hand side values to zero after each iteration. No guarantee it works.

Comment: It's possible your problem has bad numerics. Developers of commercial solvers invest a fair amount of work in fighting around such problems. It sounds as if you're hitting a degenerate corner (tie for pivot row) but rounding error is arbitrarily (and incorrectly) breaking the tie. You might try making a small random perturbation of the original RHS, compute the current RHS based on that, pick a pivot row and drop the perturbation. I think I'd be inclined to try the truncation kludge first, though.

Comment: I tried the kludge and it works on my small example which fails without the kludge. Thanks for that :) Anyway it doesn't seem to work on the larger example. May I ask why the perturbation might solve the problem? Using that a new RHS exists and might give me a different column but that one is kind of random, right? It isn't better than before or am I wrong? For me it sounds like the same as sorting the "tied" columns and testing them all.

Comment: You're correct that the perturbation approach doesn't guarantee a better column. You're (almost literally) rolling the dice. Sorting the tied columns would be more thorough but also possibly (perhaps likely) more computationally expensive.

Comment: Degeneracy should not cause an invalid basis. That's why I thought the kludge might work. With the larger example, do you again end up with a basis matrix that is singular? If so, another possibility is to do small random perturbations to the columns of the constraint matrix that are pivot choices, pivot, leave the perturbations in for a little while (to get away from that corner of the feasible region -- might take multiple pivots if there's degeneracy), then pull the perturbations out, sacrifice a small furry animal to the gods and refactor.

Comment: It depends a bit on how big I'm making the kludge. If I have a kludge which is as low as the epsilon of the floating point arithmetic I get a singular matrix again. If I make it bigger (up to 0.0000001) I don't get a singular matrix.

Comment: The cutoff for truncation would definitely need to be larger than the nominal accuracy for (I assume double-precision) numbers. Per Wikipedia (I don't keep this in memory), IEEE double precision is good for "15 to 17" significant digits. Accumulated rounding error is going to make the last few of those digits sketchy. To give you an idea, the CPLEX feasibility tolerance parameter (which is close to what you need conceptually) defaults to $10^{-6}$ and cannot be set lower than $10^{-9}$.